# Filtering data in @Pipe error

Tags: angular, typescript, filtering, grouping

I'm attempt filtering data and rendering it in htmltable.
Below my code:
In module.ts

```
import Register10Pipe = require("./register10/register10.pipe");
@NgModule({
    declarations: [
        Register10Pipe.FilterPipe
    ])
```

In my.pipe.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit, Pipe, PipeTransform, Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Pipe({
    name: 'sectionGroup'
})

export class FilterPipe implements PipeTransform {
    transform(items: any[], field: number, value: number): any[] {
        if (!items) return [];
        return items.filter(it => (+it[field]) === (+value));
    }
}
```

In my.component.ts

```
    import { FilterPipe } from './register10.pipe';
export class MyComponent implements OnInit {
    filter: FilterPipe;
......
```

HTML where data must rendering

```
    <ng-container *ngFor='let data1 of sectionList'>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="7">
                {{data1.name}}
                <button (click)="ArrRow($event)" style="float: right" id="{{data1.id}}">+</button>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr *ngFor="let data2 of (model.Register10Data | filter:'sectionGroup':data1.id); let dataIndex = index">
            <td>
                {{dataIndex}}
            </td>
        </tr>
    </ng-container>
```

sectionList it is Array of objects like myObj{number:id, string:name}
I'm getting id from this array and trying to filter data that received from server. As i understand for this in angular can be using @Pipe. I know that there are other approaches, but this one I liked more. But I getting exception.

> Unhandled Promise rejection: Template parse errors: The pipe 'filter'
>   could not be found ("
>                       
>                   
>                   ]*ngFor="let data2 of (model.Register10Data | filter:'sectionGroup':data1.id); let dataIndex
>   = index">"): e@68:20 ; Zone:  ; Task: Promise.then ; Value: Error: Template parse errors: The pipe 'filter' could not be found ("
>                       
>                   
>                   ]*ngFor="let data2 of (model.Register10Data | filter:'sectionGroup':data1.id); let dataIndex
>   = index">"): e@68:20

Comment: what is the `+` doing in the pipe?

Comment: @Christopher. it's casting the value to a number (i'm assuming)

Comment: ok - you're declaring `data` in both of your nested for loops, that probably isn't helping

Comment: A tip for debugging. You have a lot of different errors in your code. Get a version working with minimal features, then slowly work your way to the end state, adding one feature at a time and verify that each one works before moving to the next.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding parentheses around the property + filter ?

```html
<tr *ngFor="let data of (model.Register10Data | filter:'sectionGroup':'cSectionId'); let dataIndex = index">
</tr>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
 <ng-container *ngFor='let data1 of sectionList'>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="7" >{{data1.name}}
            <button (click)="ArrRow($event)" style="float: right" id="{{data1.id}}" >+</button>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr *ngFor="let data2 of (model.Register10Data | filter:'sectionGroup':data1.id); let dataIndex = index">
        <td>
            {{dataIndex}}
        </td>
    </tr>
</ng-container>
```

You can access the values from the first `ngFor` in the second one, but only if you declare differnt names `data1` and `data2` here.

If you haven't done so already, include your custom pipe in `app.module.ts`

```
...
import { FilterPipe } from './filter.pipe';

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    ...,
  ],
  declarations: [
    ...,
    FilterPipe
  ],
})
export class MyModule { }
```

Comment: Now i get folow exception: `Unhandled Promise rejection: Template parse errors: The pipe 'filter' could not be found` Maybe I'm creating @Pipe incorrectly?

Comment: Progress at least, have you included the pipe in your `app.modules.ts` declarations?

Comment: I mus includ FilterPipe class? If yes, how it is doing?

Comment: Yes - have a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/angular2/1165/pipes/3756/custom-pipes#t=201702141331159077603

Comment: I'm already using `template: require('./register10.component.html')` in In my.component.ts. In my case it is `register10.component.ts`

Comment: That is different, you need to define the filter in the global app. Let me update the answer

Comment: Look at updated question. Look at the update in question. Error all the exact same ...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/135689/discussion-between-christopher-moore-and-seva).